# Cannot find the excel trendline option

Tags: microsoft-excel

I cannot find the option to use trendline and using least fit square function in excel office 365: they seems to change the layout?
[image]

Comment: What's excel 2015? I didn't find such a version on the Microsoft website.

Comment: Its probably called office 365...I was confused

Comment: I don't have a current version of Excel, but in previous versions, there were many ways to get there: select a curve on the graph, right-click on it, and fitting a trendline was an option; IIRC, you could get to it as an option through the chart or plot area; and I think it was available on the ribbon menu once you got to the charting section.  Your picture shows the format menu but look on Chart Design, or possibly Insert --> Chart.